# python cv2.calibrateCamera throws error: objectPoints should contain vector of vectors of points of type Point3f

Tags: python, opencv

I have the code

```
img = cv2.imread("poolPictures\chessboard3.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
chessboardImage = cv2.imread("poolPictures\chessboardActual.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(img, (9,6), None)
cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (9,6), corners, ret)

chessRet, chessCorners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(chessboardImage, (9,6), None)
ret, matrix, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(corners, chessCorners, chessboardImage.shape[::-1][1:3], None, None)`
```

Running the code throws the error:

`ret, matrix, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(corners, chessCorners, chessboardImage.shape[::-1][1:3], None, None)
cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\calibration.cpp:3110: error: (-210) objectPoints should contain vector of vectors of points of type Point3f in function cv::collectCalibrationData`

chessboard3.jpg:

[image: chessboard3.jpg]

chessboardActual.jpg:

[image: chessboardActual.jpg]

results of draw chessboard:

[image: results of draw chessboard]

I have tried converting the objectpoints to a 3 dimensional vector instead of 2 by by introducing a dummy 3rd dimension - I could not find the python version for Point3f().

I also saw from here https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6002 that sometimes the error might be misleading, and that the real problem is that one of the vectors inside imagePoints is empty - I have tried printing the vectors and none are empty.

Hopefully someone can help, might just be a case of taking more pictures...

Cheers,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Zenith042 pointed out, I had image points and object points the wrong way round. However, the main issue was that instead of a numpy array for my image points like:

```
[[[ 137.5  205. ]]
[[ 143.5  206.5]]
 .
 .
 .
[[ 137.5  209.5]]]
```

I instead needed:

```
[[ 137.5 205. ]
[ 143.5 206.5]
.
.
.
[ 137.5 209.5]]]
```

Which I achieved with:

```
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(img, (9,6), None)
corners = np.array([[corner for [corner] in corners]])
```

although I suspect there is a nicer way with numpy.reshape.

I also needed the same structure for the object points, i.e.

```
objp = np.array([objp])
```

Comment: The reshape method is corners = corners.reshape(corners.shape[0],corners.shape[2])

Answer (score 4):

OpenCV also requires floats to have single precision, as per [this](https://answers.opencv.org/question/58718) question.

This means every array needs to be converted to `np.float32` before passing to `calibrateCamera`.

Comment: That's right,  `np.float` is the equivalent of C `double`. So `np.float32` must be specified instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create dummy objPoints using

```
>>> objp = np.zeros((6*9, 3), np.float32)
>>> objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:9, 0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)
>>> objp
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 2.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 3.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 4.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 5.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 6.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 7.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 8.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 2.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 3.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 4.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 5.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 6.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 7.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 8.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  2.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  2.,  0.],
   [ 2.,  2.,  0.],
   [ 3.,  2.,  0.],
   [ 4.,  2.,  0.],
   [ 5.,  2.,  0.],
   [ 6.,  2.,  0.],
   [ 7.,  2.,  0.],
   [ 8.,  2.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  3.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  3.,  0.],
   [ 2.,  3.,  0.],
   [ 3.,  3.,  0.],
   [ 4.,  3.,  0.],
   [ 5.,  3.,  0.],
   [ 6.,  3.,  0.],
   [ 7.,  3.,  0.],
   [ 8.,  3.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  4.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  4.,  0.],
   [ 2.,  4.,  0.],
   [ 3.,  4.,  0.],
   [ 4.,  4.,  0.],
   [ 5.,  4.,  0.],
   [ 6.,  4.,  0.],
   [ 7.,  4.,  0.],
   [ 8.,  4.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  5.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  5.,  0.],
   [ 2.,  5.,  0.],
   [ 3.,  5.,  0.],
   [ 4.,  5.,  0.],
   [ 5.,  5.,  0.],
   [ 6.,  5.,  0.],
   [ 7.,  5.,  0.],
   [ 8.,  5.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
```

You can then call

```
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objp, corners, img.shape[::-1],None,None)
```

You don't need to actually provide calibrateCamera with an 'actual' chessboard image.

Comment: fair point! Unfortunately, it still throws the same error. if I do img.shape[::-1] instead of img.shape[::-1][1:3], as you have, it gives the error: function takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given). I don't know if that has anything to do with it. Thanks.

Comment: @w1nter ah right, the error is due to the color in the image. You could slice out just the size, as you were originally doing, or you could

 use the grayscale image for calibration instead via
`gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`
to convert the image to gray, doing your corner finding on the grayscale image,  then using `gray.shape[::-1]`

Comment: ahh ok, ive now read the image in imread_grayscale instead, the original error still stands however.